# Offline Application With Sync Framework

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework, offlineapps

i have a client-server application and it must work offline. the application stores users data in DB (for example we save personal information of users and the date they join us and date they leave us , etc). so clients will send their Backups to server with Memory or CD.

**i want use C# + Entity Framework + SQL CE .**

but as you know when i want add Backups data to main DB (server DB) i have lots of conflict. in another application i fixed this problem by my own code ,it was hard to detect Inserted , Updated , Duplicate and Deleted Record and bad performance.important problem in this application is date conflict ,if one user join us twice in different date and different client i must accept earlier date of join and lots of annoying rules like this.

**So any good idea for me ?**

i heared about MS Sync Framework before but never use it and when i searched i cannot understand how use it in my C# project. if the sync framework is your idea please show me a good step by step tutorial of it. (i read msdn sync but i even do not know i must use it when i am creating DB or it is just C# code or its just a dll with pre made functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick search would have given you this: [Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494.aspx)

Comment: thanks that help but one part of my question is this is good for my conflict type ? i mean is this handle inserted , Updated , Deleted , duplicated row ? is this handle that date conflict i explain above ?